# Cannot Load Nanoframework firmware on ESP32 with E4000 error

Tags: c#, esp32, nanoframework

I am trying to load nanoFramework firmware onto an ESP32-Wroom-32 board (DEVKITV1).

When connected via USB the device shows up in Device Manager as COM3. I have tried connecting it via Putty and can read messages on baud rate 115200.

[image]

The device displays the restart message when EN is pressed, and when Boot+EN is pressed, device enters 'waiting for download' mode.

[image]

Despite this, I cannot get the device to show up in the device list in Device Explorer in Visual Studio
[image]
The debug window shows the following messages when I connect the USB cable connected to ESP32:
[image]

Using commend prompt, trying to flash the firmware gives the following error:
[image]

I have tried running command prompt with admin privileges but it doesn't help either. I tried forcing the device into 'waiting for download' mode aswell but that doesnt help either. Restarted visual studio, computer, that doesnt work aswell

Any idea what exactly could be going wrong. While Putty seems to be able to communicate with the device, it seems nanoframework cannot reach it.

Answer (score 2):

The E4000 error that you get it's coming from the esp tool.
Please run it again setting the output to verbose by adding:  -v  diag

Answer (score 1):

I realized the issue was caused by not holding the boot button for long enough. Apparently you have to hold it before you enter the nanoff command until you see the 'Erasing' message and you would be able to successfully download the firmware.

Comment: If I've answered your question satisfactorily please mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: It helped! I'm using an INKplate 10.

Answer (score 0):

By default nanoff uses 1500000 baud rate. Try set baud to 115200 manually:

```
nanoff --target ESP32_WROOM_32 --serialport COM3 --update --baud 115200
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause of this error is if you are using IO pins that are shared with the module flash and this is causing the esptool to fail to read the flash size from the device. You can run the nanoff command with the additional -v diag parameters to see if that is the case.